# Rails 5, active_model_serializers, where order includes and why I can't in the 'show' method of controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

#### I'm using Rails 5, gem 'active_model_serializers' and I have this situation:

**controllers/leagues_controller.rb**:

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user
  before_action :set_league, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /leagues
  def index
    @leagues = League.all
    render json: @leagues
  end

  # GET /leagues/1
  def show
    render json: @league, include: ['teams'] # Here I need some way to order
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_league
      @league = League.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**models/league.rb**:

```
class League < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
end
```

**serializers/league_serializer.rb**:

```
class LeagueSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :name, :address, :teams_num

  has_many :teams
  has_many :menus, serializer: ProductSerializer

end
```

I need to order teams by "goals" or other attribute in the team model. How to do that? And where? I can't do this below?

```
def show
  render json: @league, include: ['teams'], :order => 'goals DESC'
end
```

### What is the logic? I have to order in my serializer? In my model?

Why I can't use something like this? It gives to me "undefined method includes". Why?

```
def show
  @league = @league.includes(:team).order(goals: :desc)
  render json: @league
end
```

Comment: `@league = @league.includes(:team).order(goals: :desc)` wont' work because it is not an Active Record Scope. it is an instance of an Active Record. Instead you could add the `includes` at the point where you are pulling out the `@league` in the first place eg `@league = League.find(params[:id]).includes(:team).order(goals: :desc)` however... I think the ordering won't work with that either... what is it that you are ordering by goals when you just have a single league/team? do you mean `includes(:teams)` instead?

Comment: Yes, I need to order the includes(:teams) and I'm asking also where to include for performances.

Comment: Don't worry about performance if you can't get it to actually even work yet ;) Make it work, then make it work fast.

Comment: Ok, and how? Where I can order my included teams?

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested yet? :)

Comment: Yes, nothing: `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'include' for #<Shop:0x005617c5a70ae8>>` and/or `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'includes' for #<Shop:0x005617c5a70ae8>>`

Comment: So... do you remember the part where I said you can't do it on `@league`? it has to be on `League` - ie where you are first initialising `@league` ?

Comment: Ok, I have the code like in question. Where I can put the includes and order them? in `set_league`???

Comment: Yes if `set_league` is the place where you are pulling out the actual league using `League.find` then that is where you put the includes code :)

Comment: I tried and I got `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'include' for #<Shop:0x005617c5a70ae8>>` and/or `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'includes' for #<Shop:0x005617c5a70ae8>>`!!

Comment: That error is saying you're trying to call `include(s)` on an *instance* of the `Shop` model - which doesn't match anything we've talked about... Can you please edit your question and add the latest code you tried?  (don't change the old stuff you've got, add it as new code). That will help us to narrow down what is going on.

Comment: Actually I just came across another way you could do this... in your `League` model, where you have `has_many :teams` you can provide a default ordering eg: ` has_many :teams, :order => "some_col DESC"`

Comment: Also - the includes/order need to come before the `find` (because after that it's just an instance). so eg: `League.includes(:teams).order(:goals => :desc).find(params[:id])`